# How to debug Google App Engine scripts with PyScripter

Tags: python, debugging, google-app-engine, pyscripter

The situation is as follows: I have downloaded the Google App Engine SDK.  I have written my "helloworld" app that runs locally in my computer.  I have to use PyScripter as IDE.  I can't use Eclipse, that would not be a valid solution to my problem.

In PyScripter, I have set a "Run Configuration", so that an instance of the server runs locally (either in "run" mode or in "debug" mode), and can access the app via a webbrowser accessing "localhost".

Now, the problem is, breakpoints seem to be ignored.  I set a breakpoint, reload the browser, and the response appears without the debugger stopping at the breakpoint I had set in my own function.  I cannot debug at all.

The question is, how can I debug the app using the configuration I have described?

(Note:  I am already using the "remote" python engine within PyScripter for running the local server)

Comment: By saying `the "remote" python engine`, do you mean this http://pyscripter.googlepages.com/remotepythonengines?

Is there a reason for not using PyScripter internal engine? I do not see the noticable gain for that when running GAE SDK locally. The remote debugging seems to be more profitable when debugging processes on remote machines.

Comment: Good question! I am looking for a solution as well

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a [PyScripter's bug](http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/issues/detail?id=238). I tested in version 1.9.9.7 and the same problem is still there.